# Extract CAS Number from Downloaded Data

Tags: excel, split, powerquery, text-extraction

I have downloaded a CSV file from Pubchem containing over 5000+ records. One of the columns contains a bunch of computed synonyms where CAS Number is the records I wish to extract. Unfortunately, the CAS number isn't necessarily in the same position in this list, making splitting by delimiter more difficult. Below is the source data example and the desired output I am trying to achieve.

[image]

An older answer to a post a while back used a Regex function to extract strings of Numbers with a given length.

***fnRegexExtr***

```
let   fx=(text,regex)=>
    Web.Page(
        "<script>
            var x='"&text&"';
            var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');
            var b=x.match(y);
            document.write(b);
        </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in
fx
```

Unsure if this is possible here and unfamiliar with Regex but I'm wondering if it is possible to modify this function to extract CAS numbers. The difficulty is that CAS Numbers can be in various formats CAS Numbers are up to 10 digits long using the format xxxxxxx-yy-z.

If anyone has any alternative solutions to extracting CAS numbers with this somewhat complex data feel free to post.

Data:

cid and cmpdname can be anything.

```
1-Aminopropan-2-ol|1-AMINO-2-PROPANOL|78-96-6|Isopropanolamine|Monoisopropanolamine
1-chloro-2,4-dinitrobenzene|2,4-Dinitrochlorobenzene|97-00-7|Dinitrochlorobenzene|DNCB|Chlorodinitrobenzene|CDNB
1,2-dichloroethane|Ethylene dichloride|107-06-2|Ethylene chloride|Ethane, 1,2-dichloro-|Glycol dichloride|Dutch liquid|Dutch oil|Ethane dichloride|Aethylenchloride
1,2,4-trichlorobenzene|120-82-1|Benzene, 1,2,4-trichloro-|unsym-Trichlorobenzene|Hostetex L-pec|Trojchlorobenzene
CHLOROACETALDEHYDE|2-chloroacetaldehyde|107-20-0|Chloroethanal|2-Chloroethanal|Acetaldehyde, chloro-|Chloroaldehyde|Monochloroacetaldehyde|2-Chloro-1-ethanal
```

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the expected output of the example you gave, so we can better understand your needs ?

Comment: Hi there, Its the desired output in the image. Let me know if its difficult to read.

Comment: It would help to know what these possible formats are.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look long enough before commenting.
The difference between the expected output and the other parts of the data are small. Can you provide "rules" to make the decisions ? I'm not a chemist, and I don't think I am able to choose the good column each time. For example, why choose "chloroacetaldeyde" instead of "2-Chloroethanal" in the last column ? What are the rules ?

Comment: Hi @totok I have updated the image to make it easier. Just to confirm, the Names of the chemicals only come from the cmpdname and not the synonym. I only want to extract the CAS number from cmpdsynonym.

Comment: @JvdV This is perhaps the tricky part. CAS Numbers are up to 10 digits long using the format xxxxxxx-yy-z. Most common in my experience are those shown in the image: i.e. xx-yy-z or xxx-yy-z

Comment: What about a simple formula in Excel instead of PQ?

Comment: Ideally, PQ as I think it's quite an interesting problem for PQ regardless, however for my needs a formula as a workaround would be v useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PQ, this will pull out the contents of any item that does not contain a letter in cmpdsynonym, which I think is basically what you are looking for

```
   let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
   #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom.3", each List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Text.Split([cmpdsynonym],"|"), each if _ = Text.Remove (_,{"A".."Z","a".."z"}) then _ else null)){0})
   in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way of doing it in PQ, using `fnRegexExtr` to return the CAS; and a simple `Text.Split` to return the chemical compound name:

```
let

//Read in data and set data type as text
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Compounds"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//Transform to desired output
    Result = Table.FromColumns(
        {List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Column1], each Text.Split(_,"|")){0}}
        & {List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Column1],each fnRegexExtr(_, "\\b\\d{1,7}-\\d{2}-\\d"))},
        type table[Compound=text, CAS=text]
        )
in
    Result
```

***Original***
[image]

***Results***
[image]